# emmet working in VScode without abbreviation

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

emmet was working before but it's stopped now, I don't really know what exactly the problem is but it was working and stopped 
`VSC Version: 1.60.1`
**`settings.json`**:

```
{
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 100,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.4.0\\php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.4.0\\php.exe",
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.cursorWidth": 2,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 80,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "smart",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
    "npm.runInTerminal": false,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
    "terminal.integrated.cursorWidth": 3,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme Ocean High Contrast",
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "projectManager.git.baseFolders": [
        "business-manager"
    ],
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/css"
        }
    ],
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascriptreact": "html"
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
}
```

#### my extensions

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 4]
[image: 5]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean pretium mattis est, quis vehicula ante tempus quis. Mauris pellentesque metus eu ligula tincidunt, ac eleifend arcu fringilla. Pellentesque velit urna, feugiat vitae dolor et, mollis feugiat urna. Sed quis porta arcu. Mauris a scelerisque justo, id ullamcorper mi. Aenean cursus est a justo ultrices suscipit. Phasellus volutpat vestibulum leo ac auctor. Ut molestie pellentesque sapien ut sollicitudin. Ut tincidunt lacus risus, in mollis ante ultrices quis. Ut vehicula quis lectus non mollis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### solution 1

try to remove the live server extension

### solution 2

remove log files

### solution 3

remove vs and redownload it.

### solution 4

change your settings file to

```
{
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 100,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.4.0\\php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.4.0\\php.exe",
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.cursorWidth": 2,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 80,
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "smart",
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "workbench.editor.untitled.hint": "hidden",
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
    "npm.runInTerminal": false,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
    "terminal.integrated.cursorWidth": 3,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Community Material Theme Ocean High Contrast",
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "projectManager.git.baseFolders": [
        "business-manager"
    ],
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/css"
        }
    ],
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascriptreact": "html"
    },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
}
```